# React - set state of parent component to close modal from a child component

Tags: reactjs

I set the state of my modal component in the parent to handle opening and closing it. The initial show state is false and on a click event the show state becomes true and the modal popup appears. This is working correctly, the issue is I cannot close it. I cannot seem to to call the handleHide function in the parent component from the child.

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        show: false
      };
    }
    handleHide() {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }
    renderRow() {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}>test</td>
          <ChildModal show={this.state.show} handleHide={this.handleHide}/>
        </tr>
      );
    }
}


class ChildModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <Modal onHide={() => this.props.handleHide()} show={this.props.show}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton> 
            <Modal.Title>Test</Modal.Title> 
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body> 
                {/* some text */}
            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: got the solution ...i'm also in to similar problem ..... plz update it here ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're passing `onHide` as a prop to the `Modal` component.  Within `Modal`, you need to define what `onHide` means

Answer (score -2):

Use modal like this if you use reactstrap : 
First import all things from `reactstrap`

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
      <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal 

title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
              </ModalBody>
              <ModalFooter>
                <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
                <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
              </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
```